# SpriteKit position sometimes doesn't change node position

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, sknode

I have 3 nodes - form, formWrapper and the moving node which is self in this case. And I have this code:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if form.contains(self.position) {
        self.position = formWrapper.position
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Sometimes this self node stays on its place where the touch was ended and it doesn't move to formWrapper's position.
I tried to use SKAction like this

```
self.run(SKAction.move(to: formWrapper.position, duration: 0))
```

but it didn't help.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `form`? I assume it's a scene, and are you _sure_ you are only ending the touch in that scene?

Comment: No it's not a scene, it's a node. Actually if statement is true always, as I see that the next self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false is working. And if I add some print it's also working.

Comment: And so is `self` the scene then?

Comment: No it's a node also

Comment: Can you just provide the wireframe for this code as everything is quite hard to understand out of context.